# uploading a theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i'm trying to upload a theme in wordpress but it is giving me an error which says "Failed to connect to FTP Server localhost:21" , though I have filled in the detils for Hostname, FTP username and FTP password. how do I go about it?

Comment: Are you trying to upload it with an FTP client or through the Wordpress CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the permissions of your WordPress installation.
You'll be able to find the right permission for files and folders in here.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions